# Cannot instantiate 2-D array with dynamic size

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a class with a 2d integer array as a member. What I want, is for that member to be dynamically allocated as an `x` by `x` matrix when I instantiate a `truck` instance through the constructor. Here is my code:

```
public class truck
{
    public int[][] mat;
    truck(int x)
    {
       mat = new int[x][x];
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
                mat[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

It is giving me the following error:

> Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'

on this line: `mat = new int[x][x];`

Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: Error 2 Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']' on
' mat = new int[x][x];'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't initialize a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) like that. You have to initialize the first dimension first, and then initialize the elements:

```
mat = new int[x][];
//now you can do this:
mat[0] = new int[x];
...
```

Maybe you want a [multidimensional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) array instead?

```
public int[,] mat;
...
mat = new int[x,x];
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `[][]` you create an array of arrays. It means that each element of the first dimension contains an array.
That is why you need to initialize `x` arrays instead of just one.
You can do that by:

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++) mat[i] = new int[x];
```

If you need to create just a two dimensional matrix, you can use `int[,]` instead of `int[][]`. In this case you would be able to initialize it like `mat = new int[x,x]`